# D2L grade category routes are inaccessible to student roles

Tags: desire2learn

When accessing the D2L Valence API as a student, `/d2l/api/le/1.1/(D2LID: orgUnitId)/grades/categories/` and related `GET` requests return a `HTTP 404` error where the `orgUnitId` is a class.

The route `GET /d2l/api/le/1.1/(D2LID: orgUnitId)/grades/values/myGradeValues/` works however the categories and grades are displayed at the same level in the JSON hierarchy and there's nothing to associate between grade categories and grades.

Answer (score 0):

On the first part of your question: the user making the call to fetch grade category information must be enrolled in the course offering with a role having permissions to see grade category data. The role permissions needed to see grade category data may not be the same as the permissions needed fetch one's own grade values. However, the '404' returned is odd, and would suggest that the `orgUnitId` you passed in was not found: if the user didn't have permission to retrieve the categories, then you'd expect to get a '403' error returned, not a '404'.

On the second part of your question, the call to get my grade values returns a flat array of `GradeObject` structures. You can distinguish between the grade object types by examining the `GradeObjectTypeName` property:  for grade categories, it should say `Category`; for other grade object types, it will have the type name for that grade object (i.e. `Numeric`, `PassFail`, and so forth).